# Dot Net Installer: How to stop the "Skip" button from showing up?

Tags: installation, bootstrapper, dotnetinstaller

Here is the installer builder that I am using, version 1.10:
http://dotnetinstaller.codeplex.com/

In the config file, I have multiple Setup Configurations.
For the created bootstrapper, there will be "Skip" Button on each Configuration (except the last one). Can I stop this button from showing up? How?

Thank you very much.

Simon

Comment: Have you asked this on the project's Discussions?

Answer (score 0):

This has long been fixed/changed. The project lives in https://github.com/dblock/dotnetinstaller now.